# SELECT query including a junction table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, junction

I have three tables:

**Product**

- Product_ID
- Name
- Description
- Price

**Supplier**

- Supplier_ID
- Name
- Location

ProductSupplier

- Product_ID
- Supplier_ID

`ProductSupplier` is the junction table instead of having the many to many relationship.

I need to create a `SELECT` statement that will return two columns: the name and price of the product (not the product ID), but only if the `Supplier` is located in Australia. The supplier's location can't show up in the result.

I would know how to do this without the junction table, but this has stumped me.

Comment: It seems like a product can have many suppliers. Are you looking for products that have at least one supplier that isn't in Australia, or for products that don't have a supplier in Australia at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the following sql statement will return all products has at least Supplier located in Australia

```
select distinct p.Name,p.Price
from Product  p
inner join ProductSupplier  ps on ps.Product_ID = p.Product_ID
inner join Supplier  s on s.Supplier_ID = ps.Supplier_ID
where s.Location = 'Australia'
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I haven't seen distinct used before, what is that doing in this code?

Comment: it returns result without duplication

Comment: I got the following error message:

FROM PRODUCT AS P
             *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 1):

If you can avoid `select distinct` (and `count(distinct)`), then that is a good idea.  They incur extra overhead for removing duplicates.

So, the best approach would do the filtering in the `where` clause, using `in` or `exists`:

```
select p.Name, p.Price
from Product p
where exists (select 1
              from ProductSupplier ps inner join
                   Supplier s
                   on s.Supplier_ID = ps.Supplier_ID
              where ps.Product_ID = p.Product_ID and s.Location = 'Australia'
             );
```

This should have the best execution plan.